# optional setting in angularfire authwithpassword

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I am using AngularFire `$authWithPassword(credentials[, options])` for login. I assume [options] is `"remember"` with value of `default`, `sessionOnly`, `none`, as described [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/password.html#section-logging-in).

I tried all 3, I can not see any difference in my mobile app. I logged in my app, then kill/close my app, restart it. All 3 options let my app persist/remember username and password and logged in. Should at least `None` forget authentication data?

This is the code I use for authentication:

```
var _remember="default"; 
if (!$scope.isAutoLogin){ _
    remember="none";
    //"sessionOnly"; 
};
auth.$authWithPassword({ email: user.email, password: user.password, remember:_remember })
.then(function (authData) { 
    console.log("Logged in as:" + authData.uid); 
}).catch(function (error) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If I see it correctly it is just a matter of syntax, your login should be like this:

```
auth.$authWithPassword({
  email    : user.email,
  password : user.password
}, {
  remember: "sessionOnly"
});
```